# IsEnabled=false for parent, but a child should be enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML page with lots of components, where only of the components is a table, that looks like this

```
<UserControl>
   <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
      <FlowDocumentScrollViewer IsToolBarVisible="False">
         <FlowDocument IsHyphenationEnabled="False">
            <Table Style="{StaticResource UniversalListTemplate}" Margin="0" Padding="0">
               <Table.Columns>
                  <TableColumn Width="70" />
                  <TableColumn Width="170" />
                  <TableColumn Width="210" />
               </Table.Columns>
               <TableRowGroup>
                  <TableRow>
                     <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                           <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Time}" />
                        </Paragraph>
                     </TableCell>
                     <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                           <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Text}" />
                        </Paragraph>
                     </TableCell>
                     <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                           <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Measurement}" />
                        </Paragraph>
                     </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow Background="Gray" FontSize="0.1">
                     <TableCell ColumnSpan="5" />
                  </TableRow>
               </TableRowGroup>
               <TableRowGroup x:Name="TableDataRows"> />
            </Table>
         </FlowDocument>
      </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
   </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

All items on the page should be disabled, but I need the scrolling of this component and it should not change the colour of the items.

So can I in anyway overwrite IsEnabled for this component, so this is always enabled?

Comment: While @cheese is correct, if the parent is Disabled and the point of inheritance is that so are the children. However you could always just embed your group of Disabled stuff and what you want enabled into one Grid and just float the enabled stuff over the disabled stuff to accomplish what you want as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating a simple wrapper element that breaks the `IsEnabled` inheritance chain from the parent.

The framework's default coerce callback checks the parent `IsEnabled` value and inherits it. This control sets a new coerce callback that just returns the value directly without checking inheritance.

```cs
public class ResetIsEnabled : ContentControl
{
    static ResetIsEnabled()
    {
        IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(ResetIsEnabled),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: true,
                propertyChangedCallback: (_, __) => { },
                coerceValueCallback: (_, x) => x));
    }
}
```

It can be used like this

```xml
<ParentControl IsEnabled="False">
  <!-- Any elements here will have IsEnabled set to false, inherited from the parent -->
  <ResetIsEnabled>
    <!-- Any child elements here will have IsEnabled set to true (the default value) -->
  </ResetIsEnabled>
</ParentControl>
```

In the specific example for this question, you would wrap the `<ScrollViewer>` with `<ResetIsEnabled>` to not inherit `IsEnabled` from the parent and enable scrolling. If content of the table inside the `ScrollViewer` needs to be disabled, you could then set `IsEnabled="False"` on the table to disable all the child content of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If parent container is disabled than children are also, you can't change it

Comment: Indeed, IsReadOnly allows the scroll bar to continue to move while disabling everything else inside, but not all controls have IsReadOnly.